# How to take F# measurements to get speedups

Tags: haskell, f#, parallel-processing, measurement

Assuming a single machine with 8 cores.
In Haskell, you can compile using the `threaded` option, then during runtime use `+RTS -Nx` to specify the number of cores to be used. e.g.

```
$ myprg args // sequential run
$ myprg args +RTS -N1 // parallel run on 1..8 cores
$ myprg args +RTS -N2
$ myprg args +RTS -N4
$ myprg args +RTS -N8
```

From this, you get the runtimes using increasing number of cores, which you can then use to get speedups and plot a graph.

How would you do this in F#, assuming I have a parallel program e.g. using a parallel map in the code?

*EDIT:*
I found there are [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) e.g. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which *may* be what I need but not sure about its exact behaviour, and I would have to use it programmatically which is fine as long as it behaves as expected i.e. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` = num of cores program should use, and not parallel 'tasks' or threads.

**EDIT:**
`ProcessorAffinity` indeed limits the number of cores to use but it seems that it is not properly implemented in Mono. I checked on Windows and it seems to work. Though it is not really a good idea to use. The runtime system should be able to decide better how to manage and schedule tasks. Also, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is about "parallelism level" which basically sets the number of tasks generated, thus could be used to vary granularity.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can just set the number of CPUs in a task manager: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-processor-affinity-to-an-application-in-windows/

Comment: I am using Linux/mono. Is there a way of doing the same thing under Linux?

Comment: F# builds a native .NET assembly. An assembly follows the rules specified for runtime (CLR) which by default has affinity on all CPU cores.
You can limit CLR for a _fewer_ number of cores by setting `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity`.

Comment: @bytebuster You should make that an answer so we can upvote it--it's a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# builds a native .NET assembly. An assembly follows the rules specified for runtime (CLR) which by default has affinity on all CPU cores. You can limit CLR for a *fewer* number of cores by setting `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity`.

This answer seems to be incomplete for Mono environment. `ProcessorAffinity` value [is a bit mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx), so `0` is certainly an invalid condition. I'm also wondering why the setter did not throw an exception as described in MSDN.

I would use `schedutils` to check Mono affinity and also check if `MONO_NO_SMP` environment flag is not set.

Answer (score 2):

To quote bytebuster's comment:

F# builds a native .NET assembly. An assembly follows the rules specified for runtime (CLR) which by default has affinity on all CPU cores. You can limit CLR for a fewer number of cores by setting `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity`.

(If you add an answer leave a comment and I will delete this)

Comment: You should probably mark the answer as a community wiki (if you're not the original author).

Comment: I tried to use `ProcessorAffinity` but it does not seem to make any difference when running a parallel program on a machine with 8 cores. I would expect setting the affinity to 1,2,4,8 would have increased speedups but it isn't the case. The runtimes remain the same, as if setting this property doesn't make any difference. Any reason why this might be happening? After looking at the doc in msdn, I am tending to think that it applies to the physical processor and not processor cores.

Comment: @vis: By default any of the standard parallel libraries will attempt to use all of your cores. `ProcessorAffinity` and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` are usually used in cases where hitting all of the cores is undesired. If you are having identical runtimes after turning on only a single processor using `ProcessorAffinity` then you may have a bug in your code which is causing it to not be properly parallized. For instance a huge deal is where exactly your parallel calls are. If you are doing a trivial map but a complex operation before it sequentially for instance.

Comment: Printing the `ProcessorAffinity` before and after changing it, displays 0. I am not sure why this is so. `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity <- nativeint 2`. I running an 8 core machine on 1 processor chip.