# How to limit the cores available in an F# application? Is it sufficient to change the processor affinity for the process?

Tags: .net, f#, clr

I want to examine the scalability of an F# application that uses `MailboxProcessor<'T>`. To do that, i want to test the application by running it first on 1, then on 2, then on 4 and so on of the cores of one multicore machine. How can i limit the logical processors available to the application?

I know that i can tamper with the processor affinity, but will i get the desired results? Will they reflect running the application on different machines that have just the desired number of cores? I am concerned about the `ThreadPool` and the `TaskScheduler`: will they be configured properly or will they act as if there is no limit?

Comment: Is this question relevant? [Is it possible to limit the cores for Parallel.ForEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5512312/162396)

Comment: You can from the task manager limit the available cored, to every specific process. Start the application with a wait for input, set with task manager the number of cores, enter input, enjoy.

Comment: My problem is that i do not know how to configure a custom `TaskScheduler`/`ThreadPool`/execution context for the `MailboxProcessor<'T>`.

Comment: @ramon-snir are you referring to Set Affinity? if yes, will the ThreadPool's behavior be optimized according to the limit?

Comment: You might be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678284/how-to-take-f-measurements-to-get-speedups

Comment: @gearg100 I think that's the right feature, and I think it should be optimized correctly. pad's link seems to confirm that (I think, it's quite late to think properly), but also **points out that there is a way to do so programmatically**.